# Why the example in MSDN article need data length multiple of 16

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to use the example on the MSDN site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741(v=vs.110).aspx.

One thing I don't understand is that the data length should be a multiple of 16 
"Create the original data to be encrypted (The data length should be a multiple of 16)"
My data only 8 bytes long, what is a workaround, append 8 spaces after my data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because encoding algorithms works with data blocks, not with the single bytes. In this case block size = 16. You can just add a padding bytes to your data for right size.

Comment: For better security, add some random data to the end

Comment: No, use a standard padding such as PKCS#7 or PKCS#5. With random padding there will be no way to determine the actual length of the padding at decryption time without a priori knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to the padding to make the input data a multiple of the block size and remnove the padding after decryption. This can usually be accomplished with a padding option to the encryption function but this does not =seem to be the case with `ProtectedMemory.Protect`. The most common padding is PKCS#7, see [Padding (cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

If you will know the length of the encrypted data prior to decryption you cna padd with anything but if you may not know the length of the encrypted data prior to decryption ypou need a padding which will provide information about the padding length.